# How to handle a subquery with no results?

Tags: sql-server

I´m trying to build a query using a subquery in my WHERE condition, and when the subquery table is empty, I actually want to apply no filters to my query, and get all entries.

How can I achieve what I want?

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
m.Material,
p.Plant
FROM dbo.AllPlants AS p
JOIN dbo.AllMaterials AS m
ON p.MaterialID = m.MaterialID
WHERE p.Plant IN ( SELECT Plant FROM dbo.MyFavoritePlants);
```

If I have no Favorite Plants, I want All Plants!

Answer (score 2):

You could add second condition to handle that scenario:

```
SELECT 
m.Material,
p.Plant
FROM dbo.AllPlants AS p
JOIN dbo.AllMaterials AS m
ON p.MaterialID = m.MaterialID
WHERE p.Plant IN (SELECT Plant FROM dbo.MyFavoritePlants)
   OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.MyFavoritePlants)
```

Comment: @SeanLange Yup, but I was  a bit faster :)

Comment: @SeanLange I think this one is more efficient.

Comment: @AdnanSharif I had a feeling people would think that. Curious, why do you say that? Because I had select * in the exists? That is a common misunderstanding. It doesn't actually matter what is used for exists, it looks for rows. You can prove this easily by using select 1/0 in your exists and it works just fine. :)

Comment: @AdnanSharif Actually for EXISTS there is no difference between `SELECT *` vs `SELECT 1` or `SELECT col`. Query optimizer is aware of such scenarios so it is a matter of taste :)

Comment: @SeanLange Beacuse you used `*` instead of `1`. Not too much difference, though.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I didn't know that. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks, will try and let you guys know.

Comment: @FAlvarez https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sub query, you can use [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-left-join/). So if there is no entry from `MyFavoritePlants` table, it will ignore the `LEFT JOIN` condition.

```
SELECT m.Material,
       p.Plant
FROM dbo.AllPlants AS p
JOIN dbo.AllMaterials AS m ON p.MaterialID = m.MaterialID
LEFT JOIN dbo.MyFavoritePlants FP ON FP.Plant = p.Plant
```

Comment: This isn't what they want. They want only the favorite plants if they exist, otherwise they want all plants.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation yet to comment but this might work

```
SELECT 
m.Material,
p.Plant
FROM dbo.AllPlants AS p
JOIN dbo.AllMaterials AS m ON p.MaterialID = m.MaterialID
LEFT JOIN dbo.MyFavoritePlants FP ON FP.Plant = P.Plant
```